# How to "label" disk partition as recovery

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I bought a new SSD which is smaller than HDD I had before so I had to clone only certain partitions. The partition that contained OS, then partition reserved for OS (100MB) and lastly the recovery partition in order to be able to return my laptop to factory setup. The problem is that when cloning the recovery partition, on the SSD it it's not hidden any more and not labelled setup as recovery. It is visible as normal drive and I can access the data from Windows. Therefore I'm not allowed to go to recovery mode when hitting F10 when booting.

My laptop is SONY VAIO.

EDIT:
Or if there's a way to copy the partition exactly as it is (to stay recovery and hidden) from the old harddrive that would be great as well.

Comment: In disk management remove the drive letter for that partition by right clicking on the partition and select Change drive letters and paths, then hit remove button and it will be hidden now, as far as label you rename it in Windows explorer by right clicking on it and select rename, do this before you remove the drive letter.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but just removing the letter and hiding the recovery partition didn't work. I had clone the whole drive with MiniTool Partition Wizard, which enables cloning (physically) bigger drive to a smaller one. Took me a while to find this tool, awesome stuff, did the job.